# Run Calabash tests on Android TV emulator

Tags: android, android-tv, calabash

I'm trying to run Calabash tests on an Android TV app. The emulator does not connect.
Has anyone used this calabash for TV?

Running calabash tests:

```
calabash-android run tv-debug.apk ADB_DEVICE_ARG=emulator-5554 -p android --tags @h
```

ERROR in terminal:

```
App did not start see adb logcat for details (RuntimeError)
```